# Opening a new activity from a button that is on a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am making a card game, using fragments to flip the cards. When a certain button is clicked I would like to open a new activity. 
I have tried using the this operator in the intent however the program goes no where. Also,  I have tried using getactivity(); In the intent however it is underlined red and doesn't run.

The Class that I am starting a new activity from:
(Note there are other methods in this activity. variable donedone is set to one in a different method)

```
public class Card extends FragmentActivity {

InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
int n;
int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0,i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,m=0;
int t,p;
int bb=0,cc=0,dd=0,ee=0,zz=0;
int ww=0;
int donedone=0;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vv);

    rulepick();

    //Ad Stuff
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    requestNewInterstitial();

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override

        public void onAdClosed() {
            Button nextcard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkbutton);
            requestNewInterstitial();
            //ShowButton
            nextcard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


    Button mClickButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkbutton1);
    Button mClickButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkbutton);

    mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.checkbutton1: {
                    // do something for button 1 click

                    rulepick();
                    cardflip();
                    //if(donedone==1){
                    //Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,LastActivity.class);
                    //  startActivity(myIntent);
                    //}
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    });

    mClickButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.checkbutton: {
                    // do something for button 1 click

                    rulepick1();
                    cardflip1();
                    //if(donedone==1){
                //  Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, LastActivity.class);
                        //startActivity(myIntent);
                    //}
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    });


    //Add request stuff
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

}
```

Activity that I am going to:
    public class LastActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lastactivity);
}

}
```

Manifest File:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".LastActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".Card" />


</application>

</manifest>
```

What am I doing wrong?? 
Thanks

Comment: have you declared your activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: You need to show us your code.

Comment: I have edited and added my code. Please take a look @TedHopp

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `OnClickListener`, you need to qualify `this` so it is the enclosing activity rather than the listener itself:

```
mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.checkbutton1: {
                // do something for button 1 click

                rulepick();
                cardflip();
                if(donedone==1){
                  // Note use of Card.this instead of just this:
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(Card.this,LastActivity.class);
                  startActivity(myIntent);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I figured out the problem and it was completely unrelated to the intent. Just a stupid mistake I was making when setting donedone=1. Thanks for your help.